# jQuery plugin which allows drop down menu like google translate

Tags: jquery

I like a lot the drop down menu of google translate that allow to choose languages (from -> to).
It gives you a quick overview of all languages (options) available and it indicates with different colors the history of your choice.
http://translate.google.com/

I'm wondering if hopefully, anyone knows a jQuery plugin to transform a simply select in a drop down menu which looks like the google translate select.
Thanks,

Antonio

Comment: FYI, it looks like that's a [Google Closure Library `MenuButton` control](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_ui_MenuButton.html).

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a plugin, just some CSS positioning and use JS to show/hide the section on click.

HTML:

```
<div id="my_button">Click me!</div>

<div id="mega_menu">
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mega_menu { display:none; left:50px; position:absolute; top:50px; }
/* Position as necessary */
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#my_button').bind('click', function( e ) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var menu = $('#mega_menu');

    if ( menu.is(':visible') )
    {
        menu.fadeOut();
    }
    else
    {
        menu.fadeIn();
    }
});
```